# Spring security with external app and microservices communication

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-security, aws-api-gateway

I am Using spring boot for microservice development. I have 3 microservices deployed on AWS ecs. with application loadbalancer and AWS API gateway my microservices are accessed to outer world.

Now I want to add spring security and Oauth2 in my microservices. Does AWS api gateway really required? Because if I use AWS apigateway, I have been forced to use cognito instead of spring security. or I can directly use Application load balancer as outer world entrypoint?

Comment: I am not sure about the "forced to use cognito" part, but you can definitely use the application load balancer as outer world entrypoint + spring security and Oauth2.

Comment: @marie, Thanks. If I use Application load balancer without API gateway, and use spring security and OAuth2, for inter microservice communication, How can I bypass authentication If request came thru internal microservice?

Comment: Use a feign client that passes along your access token. I think you can find multiple examples of this. However, if I take into consideration your other question, you will need to have a spring boot app that acts as Api Gateway. Maybe have a look at JHipster, it's great to get you started.